# Decryption in Python without password

Tags: python, encryption

I am trying to open a PDF file in Python using PyPDF2 but I am getting an exception that the file has bot been decrypted. 
I am able to open the PDF manually 
Can you please suggest me ways in which I can decrypt the file programmatically without a password

Comment: is the pdf password protected, or not?

Comment: Share us what you have done so far. We cannot help you until we have a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If the file is encrypted with a password that you don't know, it's safe enough to assume that you won't be able to decrypt it in a reasonable amount of time, unless you've found a flaw in the encryption mechanism or have a supercomputer to brute-force the password.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyPDF 2 Decrypt Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26242952/pypdf-2-decrypt-not-working)

Comment: No the PDF is not password protected